# Unable to get this format using natbib and plainnat

Tags: natbib, overleaf, bibliographystyle

[image: after adding sn-basic]My tex has this commands

```
\documentclass[iicol]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout
\usepackage[authoryear,sort]{natbib}
\begin{document}

\citep{Tripathi_2019}
\citep{Singh_2020}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{Reference}

\end{document}
```

My bib file contains

```
@article{Tripathi_2019,
title = {{Use of Principal Component Analysis for parameter selection for development of a novel Water Quality Index: A case study of river Ganga India}},
journal = {{Ecological Indicators}},
volume = {96},
pages = {430-436},
year = {2019},
issn = {1470-160X},
doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ecolind.2018.09.025},
url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1470160X18307003},
author = {Mansi Tripathi and Sunil Kumar Singal},
}
@InProceedings{Singh_2020,
author="Singh, Rosysmita Bikram
and Sai Priya, J.
and Amrutha Varshini, K.
and Praneeth Kumar, S.",
editor="Zhang, Guoqiang
and Kaushika, N. D.
and Kaushik, S. C.
and Tomar, R. K.",
title="{Greywater Recycle and Reuse for Domestic and Irrigation Purposes}",
booktitle="{Advances in Energy and Built Environment}",
year="2020",
publisher="Springer Singapore",
address="Singapore",
pages="195--202",
isbn="978-981-13-7557-6"
}
```

I need an output as shown in the screenshot

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Give the `elsarticle-harv` bib style a chance.

Comment: "Not working with this style" isn't exactly specific. *what* isn't working? Are you getting error and/or warning messages? If so, what do they say?

Comment: This compile didn’t produce a PDF.  is the error

Comment: May I suggest you familiarize yourself with the makebst utility that's part of the [custom-bib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib) package? To get started, open a command window and type `pdflatex makebst`. You'll be taken through a series of multiple-choice questions (with the default answer choice clearly marked). At the end, you'll get a bespoke bst file that implements all or your formatting requirements.

Answer (score 1):

To get a format where the citation has the author names followed by the date you need to pass the option `sn-basic`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Tripathi_2019,
  title = {Use of Principal Component Analysis for parameter selection for 
    development of a novel Water Quality Index: A case study of river Ganga India},
  journal = {Ecological Indicators},
  volume = {96},
  pages = {430-436},
  year = {2019},
  issn = {1470-160X},
  doi = {https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ecolind.2018.09.025},
  url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1470160X18307003},
  author = {Mansi Tripathi and Sunil Kumar Singal},
}
@InProceedings{Singh_2020,
  author = {Singh, Rosysmita Bikram and Sai Priya, J.
    and Amrutha Varshini, K. and Praneeth Kumar, S.},
  editor = {Zhang, Guoqiang and Kaushika, N. D.
    and Kaushik, S. C. and Tomar, R. K.},
  title={Greywater Recycle and Reuse for Domestic and Irrigation Purposes},
  booktitle={Advances in Energy and Built Environment},
  year={2020},
  publisher={Springer Singapore},
  address={Singapore},
  pages={195--202},
  isbn={978-981-13-7557-6},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[iicol,sn-basic]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout

\begin{document}

\citep{Tripathi_2019}
\citep{Singh_2020}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

Be sure to place the file `sn-basic.bst` file that's found in the `bst` folder next to your document.

I used `filecontents*` and `\jobname` just not to clobber my files, use your naming scheme. Most important is *not* to load `natbib` nor to declare a `\bibliographystyle`.

[image]

Note that it's a bad habit to brace titles. Leave capitalization to the bib style and only protect the capitals that *must* be kept.

Comment: I am not getting the result